# hide() , show() not working properly in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have defined 4 main topics in seperate  tags. Each of these again have some subtopics, some of which are already shown when page loads(these are defined as seperate tables)..and the rest can be seen when clicked on more...(these are again defined in seperate tables). Now what I want is when I click on the "more..." part under one main topic, all subtopics(along with "more") from all other main topics should get hidden, only showing the other 3 main topics as it is. Here is the code I wrote:

```
    <script> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click',function(e) {
         var $panel = $("#planning_panel");
         if ($(e.target).closest("#planning_more")[0]) {
                     $panel.slideToggle('slow');
                     $("#design").hide();
                     $("#market").hide();
                     $("#techno").hide();
                     $("#designing_more").hide();
                     $("#marketing_more").hide();
             $("#technology_more").hide();
                     e.preventDefault();
         } else {
             $panel.slideUp('slow');
             $("#market").show();
             $("#design").show();
             $("#techno").show();
             $("#marketing_more").show();
             $("#designing_more").show();
             $("#technology_more").show();
         }
         var $panel1 = $("#designing_panel");
         if ($(e.target).closest("#designing_more")[0]) {
             $panel1.slideToggle('slow');
             $("#market").hide();
             $("#plan").hide();
             $("#techno").hide();
             $("#marketing_more").hide();
             $("#planning_more").hide();
             $("#technology_more").hide();
                     e.preventDefault();
         } else {
             $panel1.slideUp('slow');
             $("#market").show();
             $("#plan").show();
             $("#techno").show();
             $("#marketing_more").show();
             $("#planning_more").show();
             $("#technology_more").show();
         }
         var $panel2 = $("#marketing_panel");
         if ($(e.target).closest("#marketing_more")[0]) {
             $panel2.slideToggle('slow');
             $("#design").hide();
             $("#plan").hide();
             $("#techno").hide();
             $("#designing_more").hide();
             $("#planning_more").hide();
             $("#technology_more").hide();
             e.preventDefault();
         } else {
             $panel2.slideUp('slow');
             $("#design").show();
             $("#plan").show();
             $("#techno").show();
             $("#designing_more").show();
             $("#planning_more").show();
             $("#technology_more").show();
         }
         var $panel3 = $("#technology_panel");
         if ($(e.target).closest("#technology_more")[0]) {
             $panel3.slideToggle('slow');
             $("#design").hide();
             $("#plan").hide();
             $("#market").hide();
             $("#designing_more").hide();
             $("#planning_more").hide();
             $("#marketing_more").hide();
             e.preventDefault();
         } else {
             $panel3.slideUp('slow');
             $("#design").show();
             $("#plan").show();
             $("#market").show();
             $("#designing_more").show();
             $("#planning_more").show();
             $("#marketing_more").show();
         }
     });
    });
    </script>
```

`"#plan", "#design", "#market", "#techno"` are the ids for my 4 main topics. `"#marketing_more", "#designing_more", "#planning_more", "#technology_more"` are the ids for the 4 respective "more" links which when clicked shows rest of the topics under more with ids ending with "panel"

Now the problem with this code is, in the fourth part of the code i.e with id `"#technology_more"`, `hide()` and `show()` functions are working fine, but its not working for any other cases.
Kindly help. I am putting my html code as well :

```
    <td width="213" valign="top" height="602" align="left">
    <table class="style46"> 
          <tr><td><font color="#0000FF" face="Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif"       size="4" >Planning</font></td></tr>
          <tr id="plan"><td><table>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Planning/web-ecommerce--where-to-begin.html">Web Ecommerce</a></td></tr>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Planning/introduction-to-ecommerce.html">Introduction To Ecommerce</a></td></tr>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Planning/web-site-analysis----a-study-in-damag.html">Web Site Analysis</a></td></tr>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Planning/set-up-your-own-blog-free.html">Setting Up Blog</a></td></tr>
          </table></td></tr>
          <tr id="planning_more"><td align="right"><font size="2px" color="#FF3300">More...</font></td></tr>
          <tr id="planning_panel"><td>
          <table>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Planning/what-is-electronic-data-interchange.html">Electronic-Data-Interchange</a></td></tr>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Planning/streamline-your-website-pages.html">Streamline Web Pages</a></td></tr>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Planning/online-backup--the-simple-value.html">Online Backup</a></td></tr>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Planning/building-ecommerce-web-sites--where-d.html">Build eCommerce Sites</a></td></tr>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Planning/banned-by-google-and-back-again..html">Banned by Google</a></td></tr>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Planning/are-drop-ship-directories-really-wort.html">Know Drop Ship Directories</a></td></tr>
          </table>
          </td></tr>
          <tr><td><font color="#0000FF" face="Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif" size="4" >Designing & Hosting</font></td></tr>
          <tr id="design"><td><table>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Designing-Hosting/ecommerce-hosting-for-your-online-bus.html">Hosting for Business</a></td>      </tr>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Designing-Hosting/web-hosting-basics.html">Web Hosting Basics</a></td></tr>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Designing-Hosting/web-hosting-strategy-for-managing-mul.html">Multiple Websites Hosting</a>      </td></tr>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Designing-Hosting/domain-name-scams--have-you-fallen-fo.html">Domain Name Scams</a></td></tr>
          </table></td></tr>
          <tr id="designing_more"><td align="right"><font size="2px" color="#FF3300">More...</font></td></tr>

          <tr id="designing_panel"><td>
          <table>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Designing-Hosting/5-minute-guide-to-video-editing-for-b.html">Video Editing Guide
          </a></td></tr>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Designing-Hosting/dedicated-domain-hosting-with-windows.html">Dedicated domain hosting
          </a></td></tr>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Designing-Hosting/ecommerce-hosting-considerations.html">Ecommerce Hosting Basics
          </a></td></tr>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Designing-Hosting/ecommerce-hosting---how-to-choose-a-m.html">Choose A Merchant Account
          </a></td></tr>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Designing-Hosting/ecommerce-web-site-building--where-do.html">Web Site Building
          </a></td></tr>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Designing-Hosting/fast-web-design-for-the-skint-webmaster.html">Web Design For Webmaster
          </a></td></tr>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Designing-Hosting/finding-the-right-web-host.html">Right Web Host
          </a></td></tr>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Designing-Hosting/how-not-to-get-web-design-work.html">Right Web Designers
          </a></td></tr>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Designing-Hosting/online-powerpoint-presentation-c-con.html">Online PPT Presentation
          </a></td></tr>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Designing-Hosting/powerpoint-to-flash--a-new-trend-in.html">PowerPoint to Flash
          </a></td></tr>
          </table>
          </td></tr>



          <tr><td><font color="#0000FF" face="Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif" size="4" >Marketing</font></td></tr>
          <tr id="market"><td><table>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Marketing/the-real-secret-to-understanding-web.html">Web Statistics</a></td></tr>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Marketing/how-to-generate-web-site-traffic-for.html">Web Site Traffic For Free</a></td></tr>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Marketing/create-worry-free-sales-with-secure-s.html">Secure Shopping Cart</a></td></tr>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Marketing/7--steps-of--mega-adsense-earners.html">Adsense Earning</a></td></tr>
          </table></td></tr>
          <tr id="marketing_more"><td align="right"><font size="2px" color="#FF3300">More...</font></td></tr>

          <tr id="marketing_panel"><td>
          <table>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Marketing/affiliates-need-to-read-their-newspap.html">Suggestion for Affiliates
          </a></td></tr>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Marketing/manufacturing-outsourcing--microsoft.html">Manufacturing Outsourcing
          </a></td></tr>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Marketing/no-customer-left-behind.html">Customer Focused Site
          </a></td></tr>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Marketing/the-e-in-ebusiness-does-not-mean-ex.html">Business vs e-Business
          </a></td></tr>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Marketing/top-10-search-engine-positioning-mist.html">SE Positioning Mistakes
          </a></td></tr>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Marketing/use-your-hobby-to-launch-a-successful.html">Website on hobby
          </a></td></tr>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Marketing/when-it-comes-to-ebay--don-t-follow-t.html">Suggestions for eBay
          </a></td></tr>
          </table>
          </td></tr>


          <tr><td><font color="#0000FF" face="Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif" size="4" >Technology</font></td></tr>
          <tr id="techno"><td><table>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Technology/the-best-simple-software-for-the-busy.html">Software For Webmaster</a></td></tr>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Technology/virtual-hosting-vs-dedicated-hosting.html">Virtual vs Dedicated Hosting
          </a></td></tr>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Technology/network-monitoring-for-serious-ecommerce.html">Network Monitoring</a></td></tr>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Technology/anti-spam-at-the-enterprise-level.html">Anti-spam at Enterprises</a></td></tr>
          </table></td></tr>
          <tr id="technology_more"><td align="right"><font size="2px" color="#FF3300">More...</font></td></tr>

          <tr id="technology_panel"><td>
          <table>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Technology/causes-of-erp-failures.html">ERP Failures
          </a></td></tr>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Technology/crm-and-customer-life-cycle.html">CRM basics
          </a></td></tr>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Technology/finding-the-right-log-analyzer.html">Right Log Analyzer
          </a></td></tr>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Technology/how-i-use-email-automatic-responders.html">Email Automatic Responders
          </a></td></tr>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Technology/implementing-sap-business-one---custo.html">SAP Business One
          </a></td></tr>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Technology/is-your-website-credit-card-friendly.html">Credit Card Friendly Site
          </a></td></tr>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Technology/microsoft-dynamics-gp-customization-t.html">GP customization tools
          </a></td></tr>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Technology/microsoft-dynamics-gp--renovated-mic.html">Microsoft Dynamics GP
          </a></td></tr>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Technology/microsoft-great-plains-customization.html">GP tools Basics
          </a></td></tr>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Technology/website-buying-guide-checklist.html">Website Buying
          </a></td></tr>
          <tr><td class="style47"><a href="Technology/xhtml---kicking-and-screaming-into-th.html">Future: XHTML
          </a></td></tr>
          </table>
          </td></tr>

          </table></td>
```

Comment: You should really group these elements in a class. It will DRASTICALLY reduce the amount of code you have. In fact, can you edit your question to include your HTML. You should be able to cut down what you're doing to about 10 lines of code.

Comment: if ($(e.target).closest("#planning_more")[0])  What that means?  I think you want this instead: if ($(e.target).closest("#planning_more").length)

Comment: @Inrbob : Yes, they are unique

Comment: @Rory, that doesnt really make sense to me.

Comment: @roasted that means the first element of all in the collection

Comment: @Siddharth, you should store the elements in variables, because you plan on (re)using them all. `var plan = $("#plan"), market = $("#market");` Also, you can do `var method = $(e.target).closest("#planning_more")[0] ? "show" : "hide";` and `plan[method]();`

Comment: @EricG I mean that he should put a class on the `#plan, #design, #market` etc elements so that instead of hiding/showing them individually he can simply say `$('.myClass').show()`. Also the mechanism for looking for the closest parent `div` can be genericised.

Comment: @EricG  Ya, but what is the purpose to test in if condition a first element of a collection which is always returning only one element. Closest is not parents.

Comment: @Rory I agree, I thought you wanted to add a class for the elements that should be shown at 'runtime'. But a class in html for all elements, great idea ! :)

Comment: @roasted So to me it says that there should exist a first-element (index:0). Perhaps YOU mean `children.length>0`..?

Comment: @EricG   If($(selector).length) returns 0 or X. If X condition is true, if 0 condition is false, no need to test it using > 0

Comment: agreed, but i was aiming at the `children` part

Comment: @Siddarth, you are overruling your previous (hide/show) actions with every new if, which do in turn (on if or else) a new action.

Comment: @EricG : I am also presuming the same. So do you suggest, in this case I change my if statements to something like `e.target.id == "#planning_more"` which will match only the exact id for the element ?

Comment: So I'm not entirely sure what closest() does, but I dont think you can do that. It seems much simpler to me to add distinct eventlisteners on all panels. You are also trying to slide all panels on every click, while you only have to move 2 per time I think.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to improve the code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click',function(e) {
     var $panel0 = $("#planning_panel"),
         $panel1 = $("#designing_panel"),
         $panel2 = $("#marketing_panel"),
         $panel3 = $("#technology_panel");

     var hidePanels = false;

     if ($(e.target).closest("#planning_more")[0]) {
         $panel0.slideToggle('slow');
         hidePanels = true;
     } else {
         $panel0.slideUp('slow');
     }

     if ($(e.target).closest("#designing_more")[0]) {
         $panel1.slideToggle('slow');
         hidePanels = true;
     } else {
         $panel1.slideUp('slow');
     }

     if ($(e.target).closest("#marketing_more")[0]) {
         $panel2.slideToggle('slow');
         hidePanels = true;
     } else {
         $panel2.slideUp('slow');
     }

     if ($(e.target).closest("#technology_more")[0]) {
         $panel3.slideToggle('slow');
         hidePanels = true;
     } else {
         $panel3.slideUp('slow');
     }

     if( hidePanels ) {
        $(".byClass").hide(); // Give them a class as suggested in the comments
        event.preventDefault();
     } else
        $(".byClass").show();
     }
  });
});
```

Note that you should add a class to the panels, so u can use the `show()`/`hide()` above.